# Link behind another element's padding is not clickable

Tags: html, css

[image]

The "complete our submission form" link behind the padding (green) can't be clicked.

The reason for all of the padding (and an equal negative margin) is to compensate for a fixed top navbar when one jumps to an anchor in a long list.

I've tried messing with `z-index` but that doesn't seem to do anything. Any thoughts?

```css
h3.place-category {
  margin-top: calc(-93px + -1rem);
  padding-top: calc(93px + 1rem);
}

.places-complete-list {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
  max-width: 66.66667%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="places-content">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>... To add a place please <a href="/places/submit/">complete our submission form</a>.</p>
  </section>
  <section class="places-complete-list">
    <h3 class="place-category" id="antique-shops"><a href="/places/category/antique-shops/">Antique Shops</a></h3>
    <ul>
      <li>...</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Sure thing, sorry about that.

Comment: I don't see where you put `z-index` attribute

Comment: better to resolve your problem you can make a snippet code here. This is easier for guys who are trying to help you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `z-index` (1, 10, or whatever works for you) to `.places-content`. Also, add `position: relative` to let z-index take effect.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Wasted hours just to discover position: relative was missing. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp), have a look

> *Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky).*

Comment: Thank you, I never knew the positioning was required.